# View result of LINQ query in watch/debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq

Is there a way you can view the result of a LINQ query in Visual Studio 2010? If you add the query as a watch expression it will say "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions".

In some test code I'm aggregating the totals of a bunch of metrics for some number of children and comparing the sum to their parents value for the same metric (deep nested if-else). All my queries are in the if statements. How can I view these values without just assigning the result to a local variable? Assignment doubles my line count and aside from debugging here provides no benefit. Does anyone have a work around they use to view the results of LINQ queries in the debugger?

Comment: May be you can use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and reference your own assemblies. You can `Dump` the query and you will see the results.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov these are all integers.

Comment: @Habib I'd considered testing my code in LINQPad, but it sounds like a hell of a lot of work. At this point the best solution is eye balling the values and doing a little mental math.

Comment: There is some debug Visualizer for LINQ to SQL or Linq to Entities. For Lambda expressions you can now only ues tricks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385795.aspx

Comment: @Habib Update from 3 years later: VS2015 now supports writing lambda expressions in the Watch windows, and OzCode EAP (http://o.oz-code.com/LINQ_EAP) now allows you to analyze LINQ queries right from the debugger, no need to set up the same references in LINQPad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot currently use lambda expressions in the watch list in Visual Studio.

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Create a method that calls the desired lambda, then put that method
   call in your watch statement.
2. Set the desired lambda expression to a variable, then look at the
   contents of that variable.  Be aware that this will enumerate
   through the expression, and may cause side effects.

I would imagine this is on the list of feature requests for VS, but MSFT has not done it yet.  Hopefully this helps in the meantime.

EDIT:

GOOD NEWS!  You can now evaluate lambdas in Visual Studio 2017.  Huzzah!

Comment: +1 although I already was aware of these works arounds and neither are appealing.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal agreed.  I don't like changing code to suit my debugging needs.

Comment: At that point I may as well just put in print statements and debug like I did before I knew how to use the debugger :-&(

Comment: @evanmcdonnal nooo!  Don't go back to the dark side!

Answer (score 6):

I am digging out this old thread for the ones which are not lucky enough to use VS 2015 yet and which are still suffering from this missing feature in the previous version of VS.

It is a bit painful to have to split code just for sake of debugging.

An alternative I like to use for **Where** queries is : **DynamicQueryable**.

Let say you have a query :

```
myClass.Records.Where(rec => rec.Country.Code == "FRA")
```

Then using DynamicQueryable you can enter a watch statement which would look like:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(myClass.Records.AsQueryable(), "Country.Code == \"FRA\"").ToList()
```

It is fairly easy to write (again for Where queries), and as this is a watch statement, quite quick to update and useful for debug purpose. Think about always adding a ToList() or ToArray() to apply the projection in your watch statement automatically.

For complex Select statements, I guess it would not be that handy, but may still help.

I would also recommend to use a tool named [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com). Last version contains [LINQ debug feature which is quite awesome](http://o.oz-code.com/LINQ_EAP). You can follow the state of the collection being modified at each level of the LINQ statement.

Answer (score 5):

[In **Visual Studio 2015** you'll be able to debug lambda expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx) (it's *Preview* at the time of writing). You'll be able to add watches with lambda expressions etc.

Expression Evaluator had to be rewritten, so many features are missing: remote debugging ASP.NET, declaring variables in Immediate window, inspecting dynamic variables etc. Also lambda expressions that require calls to native functions aren't currently supported. All features will be finished when VS2015 is released.

Comment: This is great! I've had VS 2015 for about 4 months now and from using older versions of VS, I always figured LINQ queries weren't allowed in the watch window.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean (I may be misunderstanding) but I can see the results of my LINQ query by looking in the Locals window and expanding the Results view of my query variable.
[image]

Within that, I can expand ever further and see the data inside:
[image]

Comment: You assigned to a local variable. My code actually looks like this `if (parent.Invites == children.Select(x => x.Invites).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n))`. I was looking for a way to avoid adding that unnecessary assignment everywhere just so I can look at the return value of that query in the debugger.

Comment: Ah, but my breakpoint is before the local variable is assigned.  I never reach that part, with the breakpoint where it is.

Comment: Doh! Disregard what I said.  I didn't think about the result being assigned to the local variable "query". Double doh!  Sorry, mate!

Comment: I think you're wrong about that. Your image shows you breaking on line 16, the assignment happens on line 14.

Comment: Heh, yes, you're quite right.  I forgot about the local "query" variable.  I clearly wasn't thinking...clearly.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the answer. You example shows the most viable work around but it's not sufficient imo. This is apparently just a limitation of the debugger.