# How to show 2nd row on Data in Next Button Click in C# and XML database using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

i am making Questions/Answer app for windows phone 8 using C# XAML and LINQ2XML.I have database of question and answers in xml included in project.And I  want to fetch only single record of rows every time button is clicked and showing another record only when NEXT button is clicked so i am trying to get data using below code

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("hrdb.xml");
        var filteredData =
                       from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")

                       select new hrss()
                       {
                           CAT = "Zip-code type: " + (string)c.Element("Categories"),
                           QST = "City: " + (string)c.Element("Questions"),
                           ANS = "State: " + (string)c.Element("Answers")
                      };
```

but this code does not Help or work so what to code there, and on NEXT button click event to fetch next record data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and take first. You will increament the variable passed to skip on each Next button click.

```
 var filteredData =
                   (from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")

                   select new hrss()
                   {
                       CAT = "Zip-code type: " + (string)c.Element("Categories"),
                       QST = "City: " + (string)c.Element("Questions"),
                       ANS = "State: " + (string)c.Element("Answers")
                  }).Skip(indexOfNext++).First();
```

You can declare the variable at class level scope so that `increament` will avaiable on next button click. You would probably need to initialize indexOfNext with 1.

**Edit**

As you need list instead of single record you can use [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of First

```
 var filteredData =
                   (from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")

                   select new hrss()
                   {
                       CAT = "Zip-code type: " + (string)c.Element("Categories"),
                       QST = "City: " + (string)c.Element("Questions"),
                       ANS = "State: " + (string)c.Element("Answers")
                  }).Skip(indexOfNext++).Take(1);
```

Comment: You have to declare indexofNext, I have already mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: First gives you single record if you need list then you Take, check my updated answer.

Comment: What exception ? you might reached the last record

Comment: How many records you have ? do you get exception on executing query?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in Next button event handler and check on what statement you getting exception

Comment: Check if you have record in filteredData, if yes then you have to check if you have right mapping of data columns with grid columns and there is nothing wrong with query

Comment: how to check if i have data in filteredData?

Comment: check it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620819/view-result-of-linq-query-in-watch-debugger

Comment: i have declared like this :int indexOfNext = 1; and then used your code but it doesnot work so am i declaring in wrongway?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be initialized with 1.

Comment: wow got the solution i was declaring it on button click.and now i have declared it out of it