# On android project LINQ not working in quickwatch

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple android project in Visual Studio 2015 Professional. LINQ is working in the code as normal, but I can not use LINQ in quickwatch for debugging. It just says

> Expression not supported.

I tried casting `asd2` to list, but still the same.

Is this expected behavior? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. Please have a look at: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620819/view-result-of-linq-query-in-watch-debugger)

Comment: This post is almost 4 years old. I can clearly remember using LINQ in quickwach just yesterday and it worked fine, but it does not work on android project. It works just fine on webforms, console, mvc, wpf